# Changing CSS property if no input is provided (Angular JS)

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am making a quiz using angular js.The first page of the quiz requires you to enter your name and doesn't allow you to go further if no input is provided.I want to animate input field more like the shake animation on this site (http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) if the input field is empty and the user presses the start button.Please help me out.

CODE html :

```
            <p>What's your name?</p>
            <input type = "text" class = "playername" ng-model = "playername">
            <h2>Welcome {{playername}}!</h2>
            <p>Click start if you're ready!</p>
            <p class = "btn" ng-click = "startQuiz()">START</p>
```

CODE angular :

```
 $scope.presentQues = -1;
    $scope.startQuiz = function(){
        if ($scope.playername != null){
            $scope.presentQues = 0;
        }
    }
```

PS. this is not the full code.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @Chris's answer, if you wrap it in a form, you can also use the form.$submitted variable to check if the form has been submitted.

`ng-class` uses the following format: `ng-class={'css-class':truthy-condition-to-evaluate`

Try the following code (this will have to  be changed if you already are wrapping everything in a form):

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
      <form name="myForm">
        <p>What's your name?</p>
        <input type = "text" name="playername" class = "playername" ng-class="{'animated shake': !ctrl.playername && myForm.$submitted}" ng-model = "ctrl.playername">
        <h2>Welcome {{ctrl.playername}}!</h2>
        <p>Click start if you're ready!</p>
        <input type="submit" class = "btn" ng-click = "startQuiz()" value="START">
      </form>
    </div>
```

Now, if the player submits the form without typing anything, angular will apply the `animated` and `shake` css classes to the text input.

[Look at my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2kmAds02Z2cb0xla7Fb0?p=preview) to view it in action.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of doing this, one I can see is using ng-class.

```
<!-- add class 'bounceInUp' if the scope var 'isEmpty' is true -->
<input type="text" class="playername" ng-class={'bounceInUp':isEmpty,} ng-model="playername">
```